# Programming A PSP Application And Keep Getting A Linker Error (Undefined Reference)

Tags: c, linker-errors, pspsdk

I do not know why I keep getting this linker error because I linked the right library I am sure of it unless I am linking the wrong one but maybe someone knows which is the right library for the function SonyOskGu. The error is: main.c:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `SonyOskGu(char*, unsigned int, char*, char*, int)'. The code is below:

```
#include <psposk.h>
#include "atoi.h"
PSP_MODULE_INFO("OSLib Sample", 0, 1, 1);
PSP_MAIN_THREAD_ATTR(THREAD_ATTR_USER | THREAD_ATTR_VFPU);
#define printf oslPrintf
#define ERROR_SUCCESS 0
#define ERROR -1;
int main(void)
{
    oslInit(0);
    oslInitGfx(OSL_PF_8888, 0);
    oslInitConsole();
    oslInitAudio();
    printf("Press Any Key To Start OSK In Order To Enter Path Of Audio File To Play Audio:");
    char* path = (char*)malloc(255);
    SonyOskGu(path,0xff918f8c,0,0,100);
    printf("The path is");
    OSL_SOUND* sound = oslLoadSoundFile(path, OSL_FMT_NONE);
    if (sound == NULL){
        oslAssert(sound == NULL);
        oslEndGfx();
        oslQuit();
        return ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Press X To Play Or Press O To Stop!");
        int key = oslWaitKey();
        if (key == OSL_KEY_CROSS)
        {
            oslPlaySound(sound, 0);
        }
        else if (key == OSL_KEY_CIRCLE)
        {
            oslStopSound(sound);
        }
    }
    oslEndGfx();
    oslQuit();
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

**The makefile is below:**

```
TARGET = test
OBJS = main.o  

INCDIR = 
CFLAGS = -G4 -Wall -O2 
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
ASFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

LIBDIR =
LDFLAGS =
STDLIBS= -losl -lpng -lz \
  -lpspsdk -lpspctrl -lpspumd -lpsprtc -lpsppower -lpspgu -lpspaudiolib -lpspaudio -lm -lpsposk -lpspgum -lpspgu -lpng -lz 
LIBS=$(STDLIBS)$(YOURLIBS) 


EXTRA_TARGETS = EBOOT.PBP
PSP_EBOOT_TITLE = PSP Audio Player
PSP_EBOOT_ICON = ICON0.png

PSPSDK=$(shell psp-config --pspsdk-path)
include $(PSPSDK)/lib/build.mak
```

Comment: A Japanese SDK that uses char*?  Knee-jerk was "it's gotta be SonyAskGu".  Never mind.

Comment: OSK means On Screen Keyboard it is not japanese

Comment: It is in Japan.  Never mind x 2.  I work for Sony, bit of an insider joke perhaps.  Cold fact is that PSP development is *really* obscure, there's no sharing going on and your question is already the top google hit for "sonyoskgu" out of a handful.  Which makes this, sadly, an unanswerable question unless you're lucky enough to cross paths with a psp developer.  Fret a bit about the backslash in your makefile, double-check the name of the library in which the symbol is defined.  Check for C vs C++ compilation, that's all I can think of.  Good luck.